# comparison operators in js.erb files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a file called new.js.erb that contains this line:

```
if( $('#user_password').val().length < 6 )
```

For some reason, the less-than symbol breaks down the whole file. I think Rails is seeing the < symbol as the beginning of a tag for some reason. I just want to check if the value in the user_password field has a string length less than 6. Is there a way to do this in jQuery in a js.erb file?

Amazingly, all my Googling and SO searching have not uncovered a solution.

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask for it.

Thank you for any help!

More code for mu (I can guarantee everything above and below this block is working fine):

```
        if( $('#user_password').text().length < 6 )
        {
            $('form.edit_user').submit();
            popup.unload();
            $('#send_after_pass').show();
            $('#send_after_pass').click(function(e) {
                $(this).hide();
                $('form.new').submit();
            });
        else
        {
            $('#errors').html("Password must be 6 characters or longer.");
        }
```

EDIT: My bad on the bogus quote! Pretend it was never there... That isn't what caused my problem, though.

Comment: you're mixing ruby code interpreted on server and js code which needs client.

Comment: Why you have " at start of the if? And not end. Whole block of code doesn’t say anything to me.

Comment: @apnea diving, that's what .js.erb files are supposed to do, let you create JS files after being processed by erb. But I don't see any ruby code there, just a bogus quote.

Comment: @Dave Newton: bogus quotes could be a ruby if with client condition :)

Comment: ... then the js.erb file doesn't contain that line, its render does.

Comment: That single line tells us nothing useful, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I know the error is that line. I've made sure everything else is fine.

Comment: Nothing personal but I don't believe it. That line may be showing the problem but something else is at fault, it could be as simple as a missing quote somewhere but we don't know enough to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any ERB in the code you posted but there is a missing closing brace, your code should look more like this:

```
    if( $('#user_password').text().length < 6 )
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        $('#errors').html("Password must be 6 characters or longer.");
    }
```

Note the closing brace I added above your `else`.

Comment: @batch: No worries, staring at the bug all day while saying "it couldn't possibly be that" is just part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to reverse the condition, like this and see if it is indeed the operator?

```
if (6 > $('#user_password').val().length)
```

Comment: No dice. I know I can do comparisons with ==, it's just the < and > signs that seem to be a problem.

Comment: Okay, I can't reproduce that particular error with Rails 3.1.0 inside a .js.erb file. Went even so far as to implement the exact same if-clause